# I have a WiFi problem, what commands do I need to run so I can be best helped?

Tags: wireless, command-line, output

I am trying to ask a question about getting my WiFi to work but I don't know what information to add to my question to get help, what do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few commands that should help us

```
ifconfig
```

> This displays the  status  of  the  currently  active interfaces.  If a single interface argument is given, it displays the status of the given interface only; if a single  `-a`  argument  is  given,  it  displays the status of all interfaces, even those that are down.

```
iwconfig
```

> Iwconfig  is  similar  to ifconfig(8), but is dedicated to the wireless interfaces. It is used to set the parameters of the  network  interface which  are  specific  to the wireless operation (for example : the frequency).  Iwconfig may also be used to display  those  parameters,  and the wireless statistics (extracted from /proc/net/wireless).

These commands give out a lot of info, sometimes 50+ lines together. To make it easier, you can use the following commands instead:

```
ifconfig | pastebinit
iwconfig | pastebinit
```

Will give out 2 links after you have run them both. Add them to the question instead of the output.